# How to do 301 redirect in herokuapp free hosting?

Tags: heroku, redirect

I am trying to do 301 redirect in my **herokuapp**. How can I do it. I have used `<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.herokuapp.com">`. And I have also used this tag for every page with the url of the page. Still I failed to fix **301** redirections problem in my heroku website.

With url `http://mysite.herokuapp.com` website is working but with url
`www.http://mysite.herokuapp.com` it shows

> This site can’t be reached

Yoast seo shows this message

> "Warning, no 301 redirects are in place to redirect traffic to your
> preferred domain. Pages that load successfully both with and without
> www. are treated as duplicate content! "

For this problem my website is not indexing in google, I think. How can i show my website in google search.
Note: I have submitted my website to google search console and verified it.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something called htaccess

There should be a file in the root of your web directory called ".htaccess" If not create one.

You want a rule something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.herokuapp.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.herokuapp.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should redirect www traffic to a none www prefix

Comment: But how to submit .htaccess file in heroku

Comment: You should have FTP Access? juts upload it to the root directory

Comment: Yes I have. I have uploaded .htaccess file to root directory. But heroku is not accepting .htaccess file as it is not apache server. In that case what should I do?